# Copy values of input fields to corresponding input field in next table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which represents a month and heach cell has a couple of input fields.
Now i want to add a Button to copy the values of all not hidden fields to the corresponding fields in the next cell ().
However I'm bad ad jQuery and cannot get this to work.
The Markup is added via an Ajax request, but imho that should be no problem, as I'm using the documents "on" event.

**Edit:**
With "next cell" i mean the second  tag in my markup. I want to copy the values from the cell with `<li class="disabled"><span>3</span></li>` to the cell with `<li class="disabled"><span>4</span></li>`. This should be done by clicking on `<li class="next copyNext"><a href="#">→</a></li>`

My markup:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<ul class="pager">
                <li class="previous"><a href="#">←</a></li>
                <li class="disabled"><span>3</span></li>
                <li class="next copyNext"><a href="#">→</a></li>
            </ul>

<select class="form-control" id="Staffings_0__CenterId" name="Staffings[0].CenterId">
<option value="13">ACD</option>
<option value="142">AG</option>
<option selected="selected" value="51">HINS</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<ul class="pager">
                <li class="previous"><a href="#">←</a></li>
                <li class="disabled"><span>4</span></li>
                <li class="next disabled"><a href="#">→</a></li>
            </ul>

<select class="form-control" id="Staffings_1__CenterId" name="Staffings[1].CenterId">
<option value="13">ACD</option>
<option selected="selected" value="142">AG</option>
<option value="51">HINS</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.copyNext', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var containingTd = self.parents('td');
    containingTd.children("input[type!='hidden']").each(function (index, element) {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        var nameArr1 = name.split('[');
        var nameBeforeIndex = nameArr1[0];
        var nameArr2 = nameArr1[1].split(']');
        var index = parseInt(nameArr2[0]);
        var nameAfterIndex = nameArr2[1];
        var nextIndex = index + 1;
        var nextName = nameBeforeIndex + '[' + nextIndex + ']' + nameAfterIndex;
        var nextElement = $(this).next("name=['" + nextName + "']");
        nextElement.val(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't get anything from your fiddle. what do you mean by 'next cell'? i don't see any 'next empty' cells. it's not clear what you want to do with that fiddle..

Comment: I hope my edit makes it clear what i mean with "next cell". If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script contained 2 problems:
1. It only searches for input elements, but I am using select elements.
2. var nextElement... The square Bracket has to be in front of name and ' and " had to be switched.

Here is my new script which is working as intended:

```
$(document).on('click', '.copyNext', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var containingTd = self.parents('td');
    var children = containingTd.find("input[type!='hidden'],select[type!='hidden']");
    children.each(function (index, element) {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        var nameArr1 = name.split('[');
        var nameBeforeIndex = nameArr1[0];
        var nameArr2 = nameArr1[1].split(']');
        var index = parseInt(nameArr2[0]);
        var nameAfterIndex = nameArr2[1];
        var nextIndex = index + 1;
        var nextName = nameBeforeIndex + '[' + nextIndex + ']' + nameAfterIndex;
        var nextElement = $('[name="' + nextName + '"]');
        nextElement.val(value);
    });
});
```